# Why isn't chmod doing what I want it to?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have created short bash script to run some program 10 times and save the output to a file. While I was setting the executable permissions I thought that it would be nice to remove the write permission, so that the script can not be changed without sudo/root access. But what I got was this:

```
use@ubuntu:~/some/folder$ sudo chmod -w Run_SIM.sh 
chmod: Run_SIM.sh: new permissions are r-xrwxr-x, not r-xr-xr-x
```

Why?

Comment: type `id; sudo id` and you'll note the ID is different for the sudo command. you told it to `chmod -w` for a different ID to what you think...  (maybe use `sudo chmod o-w..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short because you're removing the permision for user when you do not specify what to change. You can specify which of the `u`ser, `g`roup, `o`ther to set permissions for:

```
$ ls -l bar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 0 Nov 11 10:52 bar 
$ chmod u-w bar 
$ ls -l bar
-r-xrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 0 Nov 11 10:52 bar
$ chmod g-w bar 
$ ls -l bar
-r-xr-xrwx 1 vidarlo users 0 Nov 11 10:52 bar
$ chmod o-w bar 
$ ls -l bar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 vidarlo users 0 Nov 11 10:52 bar
```

The u, g, o in front of the permission indicates which of the permission fields to change - for user, group and other.

In addition you have the special `a`ll:

```
$ chmod a+w bar
$ ls -l bar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vidarlo users 0 Nov 11 10:52 bar
```

A shorthand commonly used by many is the octal permissions, which is built up with three digits, 0-7. First digit represents user, second group and third other.

In the octal system, 1 means expecute, 2 means write, and 4 means read. You add together the modes you want, so read and execute is 5, and read only is 4. To make the file read + execute for all, and write for owner in octal you'd do `chmod 755 filename`. A mode of 740 would be all for owner, read for group and none for other.

The good thing about octal modes is that you set all modes at once, so theres no *hidden* surprises left over.

To reserve editing of a script for root, you'd have to first set the owner of the file to root, using `sudo chown root:root filename`, and then `sudo chmod g-w,o-w filename` - or using octal `sudo chmod 755 filename`

If you go to line 301 of [the source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c) you'll see a the source code responsible for printing this warning message. Basically it calculates what *naive* users may intend, and print the difference. It's slightly interesting behaviour I was not aware of :)

Comment: But setting the x permissions has worked with "chmod +x". The permissions were correctly set even if I did not use "a+x". In the end I did use the octal way to do it. It is just that is simpler to do "-w" than to lose few seconds to work out which number will do what I want.

Comment: Indeed it does. I have no clear answer why it does that - except that I guess it may be by convention, as most binaries are expected to be available to all users. I must admit I've always used octal permissions, so it's not bee much of an issue.

Comment: The thing is that chmod seems to know what I wanted to do, just because it has made that comment about new permissions. It is the 1st time I have seen chmod making a comment...

Comment: If you go to line 301 of [the source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c) you'll see a brief explanation. Basically it calculates what *naive* users may intend, and print the difference. It's slightly interesting behaviour I was not aware of :)

Comment: Nice... Edit that to your answer and I will accept it... I was just thinking about searching for source... Thanks!

Comment: The question remains though: _why_ does `-w` not affect all three write permissions, while `+x` _does_ affect all three execute permissions? The answer is that bits that are set in `umask` won't be affected by `+*` and `-*` modifiers. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/718782/605954) for more details.